# How to add edge which follows geometry

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have created a rough head model and added a subdivision surface modifier then set the mesh to follow geometry with the 'adjust edit cage to modifier'. See below:

[image]

I want to add a couple of edges back but when I click two vertices and press F, I get the following result:

[image]

I don't know why this 'pinching' is occurring but is there a way I can add the missing edges so that they are smooth and follow the geometry?

Comment: Do the 2.8 counterpart of J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>F</kbd> creates an edge between the 2 vertices but it won't cut the face, it will just create an edge over the face, what you need to use is <kbd>J</kbd>, which will cut the face. You can also use the knife tool: <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, and, since BLender 3, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through to the mesh, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut perpendicularly.

Comment: The J command worked perfectly, thanks for your answer!